# Kafka Listener issues giving null values

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jaxb, listener, jackson-databind

I have below code in my kafka reciever listener class

```
@EnableKafka
@Service
@Component
@Slf4j
public class MessageListener{
@Autowired
@Qualifier("MessageBeanService")
@KafkaListenter(topic={"test-topic}, autoStartup="true" groupId="test-consumer-group")
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void receiveMessage(@Payload String message) throws JsonProcessingException
ObjectMapper objMapper=new ObjectMapper;
objMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, FALSE);
CartSt msg=objMapper.readValue(messages, CartSt.class)
```

CartSt has sub objects like Item, Price, Quantity.
But i see those sub objects getting populated as null values.
ObjectMapper is from fasterxml.jackson.databind jar package.
How to resolve these issues and populate correct non null values for the sub objects Item. Price, Quantity of CartSt main object.
Please advise

Comment: Also posted here: https://coderanch.com/t/770476/java/Kafka-Listener-issues-giving-null#3530918

Comment: How is the cart class annotated for the json attributes?